# Updating HttpMessageHandler or Creating Typed HttpClients in runtime with Network Credentials

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I need to pass network credentials to impersonate a domain user during application runtime based on the end user using the application. I haven't able to figure out how generate an HttpClient through the Services.AddHttpClient and HttpClientFactory in which is tied to an individual user.

```
        var httpClientBuilder = services
            .AddHttpClient<SomeHttpClint>()
            .ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(sp => new HttpClientHandler
            {
                AllowAutoRedirect = false,
                UseCookies = false,
                Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "pass", "domain")
            });
```

So my questions are as follows:

1. Is it possible to use named or typed HttpClientFactories to generate  HttpClients that would represent an individual user? Or is there a better solution to generating a bunch of HttpClients bound to individual users?
2. Is it possible to access an http client factory outside of injecting it into a controller, say such as Middleware Type?

Comment: This code configures *dependency injection* for HttpClient. This means that if your controller, or any other type that can be created by DI, requires an `SomeHttpClient` dependency, it will receive it from the DI container. It's possible to ask for named clients too. In the worst case you could add the *factory* as a DI dependency instead of the typed client

Comment: As for #2, you're effectively asking to do what DI already does. You gain nothing by that.

Comment: [This article](https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/httpclientfactory-named-typed-clients-aspnetcore) shows how you can inject the HttpClientFactory itself as a dependency and ask for named clients.

Comment: Using `IHttpClientFactory` directly along with named clients, alone, does not solve the problem. You're still expected to register the named clients at compile-time. Perhaps you can use a delegating handler? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-2.2#outgoing-request-middleware

Comment: @ChrisPratt I had looked into delegating handlers, but I don't think it's possible based on what I've seen in [corefx](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/8e551d4dc7464a465b00ac1bf9a632ea9c3bb5a1/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/SocketsHttpHandler/HttpConnectionPool.cs) source code. The credentials are tied to the client handler and client handler can't be changed after initialisation of the client.

Comment: So any solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

you can register client in runtime. here is my workaround code.
define 2 class:

```
public class DynamicHttpClientFactoryOptions : IConfigureNamedOptions<HttpClientFactoryOptions>
{
    private readonly DynamicHttpClientFactoryWrapper _options;

    public DynamicHttpClientFactoryOptions(DynamicHttpClientFactoryWrapper options)
    {
        _options = options;
    }

    public void Configure(HttpClientFactoryOptions options)
    {
    }

    public void Configure(string name, HttpClientFactoryOptions options)
    {
        if (!_options.TryGetValue(name, out var configure)) return;

        configure(options);
    }
}
public class DynamicHttpClientFactoryWrapper : ConcurrentDictionary<string, Action<HttpClientFactoryOptions>>
{
    
    public HttpClient GetOrCreateClient(string name, Action<HttpClientFactoryOptions> optionsBuilder)
    {
        if (!ContainsKey(name) || !TryGetValue(name, out var action))
        {
            TryAdd(name, optionsBuilder);
        }

        
        //you can store serviceProvider in startup class
        var factory = _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>();
        return factory.CreateClient(name);
    }
}
```

how to use:
register:

```
services.AddHttpClient(...);
services.AddSingleton<DynamicHttpClientFactoryWrapper>();
services.ConfigureOptions<DynamicHttpClientFactoryOptions>();
```

get by ms DI:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    private readonly DynamicHttpClientFactoryWrapper _wrapper;

    public SomeClass(DynamicHttpClientFactoryWrapper wrapper)
    {
        _wrapper = wrapper;
    }
    
    public async Task Work()
    {
        var client = _wrapper.GetOrCreateClient(name/*userid or something else*/, options =>
        {
            options.HttpClientActions.Add(c =>
            {
                c.BaseAddress = new Uri("...");
            });
            options.HttpMessageHandlerBuilderActions.Add(handlerBuilder =>
            {
                var handler = new HttpClientHandler
                {
                    Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "pass", "domain")
                }

                handlerBuilder.PrimaryHandler = handler;
            });
        });

        var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
        //do your work...
    }
}
```